# open html file to read its source for searching for a particular tag

Tags: file, python-3.x, unicode

I'm unable to open an html file in read mode to search for a string match in its source.

```
fo = open("htm1.html", "r");
str = fo.read(10);
print("Read String is : ", str);
fo.close();
```

This is not working.  I am getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/myProjects/malCode.py", line 34, in <module>
    str = fo.read(10);
  File "C:\Python33\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 6040: character maps to <undefined>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not specify the encoding, [`open()` will use `locale.getpreferredencoding()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#open); in your case `cp1252`. This is a problem because the HTML file employs a different, as-yet-undetermined encoding. Which encoding happens to have been used is a nice thing to know. Failing that you can give it a go with some common encodings like `'utf-8'` or `'latin-1'.` For example:

```
with open("htm1.html", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fo:
    sample = fo.read(10)
```

(Minor syntactical note: line-ending semicolons are not required.)